Experiment in prison setting with half guards and half prisoners
I'm trying to remember the title to this movie that I saw. I know it was on HBO when I saw it about 2 years ago. The plot is this group of males are brought into this prison for an experiment. Half of the group is designated as guards and the other half are prisoners. As one would expect, power got to the heads of the guards and they started to act differently than their normal selves. Then the roles are switched and the "New" guards are vengeful against the old guards. IF someone could help me out with the name, that would be spectacular.

The title has it: the name of the film is "The Experiment"

Unemployed Travis (Adrien Brody) enrolls in a psychological role-playing experiment, where participants assume the identities of inmates and prison guards in an empty jail, with the promise of a $1,000-a-day reward. Another participant, Barris (Forest Whitaker), embraces his correctional officer role with a vengeance, and before long, the prisoners find themselves at the mercy of their keepers. All the test subjects discover how easily violence and cruelty can manifest itself in human behavior...

This film is actually a remake of Das Experiment, but toth films are a dramatization of a real study which surely every psychology student in the world has heard of, if not at some point studied, The Zimbardo: otherwise known as The Stanford Prison Experiment.
Unlike the experiment within the film, IRL the observation became far too violent and after 6 days ways halted, due to fears for the safety of the volunteers. There was also no $14,000 prize for participation: the real sum was a paltry $15 per day (roughly equivalent to $85 in 2014). 

That's it. And it's so original. Thanks.

There's no switch of roles, though. But still the obviously correct answer.

@NapoleonWilson, IRL they did switch roles, which is why the OP may have got confused: that's when the real violence started... the entire study is available for reading here.

@JohnSmithOptional The plot summary on Wikipedia doesn't suggest a switch of roles in the 2010 version and the 2001 version definitely didn't have it. But nevermind. Though, I guess the Stanford experiment has inspired many things, I also remember an episode of the TV-show Life featuring a version of it.

@NapoleonWilson, ...see previous comment, and if neccessary, check case notes from original study...

@JohnSmithOptional Oh sorry, I missed/didn't understand the "IRL". Got it.
